# Rmarkdown add footnote to figure caption

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, caption, footnotes

I would like to include a footnote within a figure caption in an R markdown report rendered to both PDF and HTML (report is based on `bookdown`/`thesisdown`/`huskydown`).
The ideal would be to use text references:

```
(ref:foo-footnote) Text in the footnote.
Can span multiple lines, but has to start on the line of the text reference.

(ref:foo-caption) My text with a footnote.^[(ref:foo-footnote)]
```

#### What I tried

````
---
title: "Footnote in Caption"
author: "Test"
output: html_document
#output: pdf_document
---

## Figure with caption which includes a footnote
<!-------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!-- Reference the figure "by number" as usual with \@ref(fig:foo) -->
<!-- Reference the figure "by name" by adding an anchor above the figure: -->
<!-- \hypertarget{fig:foo}{} -->
<!-- which can be referenced by: -->
<!-- [my linked text](#fig:foo) -->

(ref:foo-caption) My caption^[Footnote text.].
(ref:foo-scaption) My short caption

```{r foo, echo=FALSE, out.width='100%', fig.align = "center", fig.cap='(ref:foo-caption)', fig.scap='(ref:foo-scaption)'}
knitr::include_graphics(paste0(fig_path,"foo.png"), auto_pdf = TRUE)
# if auto_pdf = TRUE: includes PDF version of figure if available in same folder
```
````

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reproducible example for PDF outputs from `bookdown`, but I haven't figured out how to make it work for HTML.

Essentially you need to include `\\protect\\footnotemark` in the figure caption, and then afterwards in the Rmd text (outside the chunk) include `\footnotetext{Here is the footnote text.}` with your text.

````
---
title: "Footnote in caption"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(bookdown)
```

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is a figure caption with a footnote.\\protect\\footnotemark", out.width="100%"}
plot(pressure)
```

\footnotetext{Here is the footnote text.}

Here is a plot in Figure \@ref(fig:pressure).
````

The original solution for raw LaTeX came from Tex StackExchange (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption) and I've just adapted for Rmd which requires you to use a double slash for LaTeX commands inside captions.

Comment: This is only sort of working for me. It makes the Rmarkdown file skip a footnote number and puts the corresponding footnote on the page above the figure.